# Mysql select from two tables join

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have two tables "employees" and "dependents",

> ```
>     Employees
>   |employee_No| Employee_name  |
>   |1558       | Bean           |
>   |1557       | Juliet         |
>   |1556       | Zeke           |
>
>     Dependents
>     
>   |employee_No| dependent_name | relationship|
>   |1558       | Kelvin         | Son         |
>   |1558       | Mary           | Daughter    |
>   |1556       | Janet          | Spouse      |
> ```

is there a way i could get this data in one MySQL statement and display using php i.e. loop employees and dependent under that employee then move to the next employee.

current php code is

```
$employees = select_all_employees()
foreach ($employees as $covered){
  echo $covered['Employee_name'].'<br/>';
$get_dependent = $select_dependent($covered["employee_No "]);
 if($get_dependent != 0){
     foreach($get_dependent as $details){
      echo $details['dependent_name '].' '.$details['relationship'].'<br/>';
     }
  }
}
```

this takes too much time to load when there are thousand employees and dependents

expected outcome

```
|employee_No| dependent_name | relationship|
--------------------------------------------
|1558       | Bean           | principal   |
|1558       | Kelvin         | Son         |
|1558       | Mary           | Daughter    |
|1557       | Juliet         | principal   |
|1556       | Zeke           | principal   |
|1556       | Janet          | Spouse      |
```

Comment: Hint: `JOIN`.  You should at least also show us the expected output you want to see.

Comment: i have added expected result,

Comment: How principal come in your relationship. And Bean is employee not a dependent_name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to get the results you want is with a `UNION` of the rows of the `Employees` table with the `JOIN` of the `Employees` with their `Dependents`. We do this `UNION` as a derived table so that we can then order the results by `employee_No` and also place the `principal` first for each `employee_No`. By doing it this way your PHP code becomes a simple loop over all the results.

```
SELECT employee_No, Employee_name AS dependent_name, 'principal' AS relationship
FROM Employees
UNION ALL
SELECT e.employee_No, d.dependent_name, d.relationship
FROM Employees e
JOIN Dependents d on d.employee_No = e.employee_No
ORDER BY employee_No DESC, relationship = 'principal' DESC
```

Output:

```
employee_No dependent_name  relationship
1558        Bean            principal
1558        Mary            Daughter
1558        Kelvin          Son
1557        Juliet          principal
1556        Zeke            principal
1556        Janet           Spouse
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eeN6FCvAjVwYePbhyYwPzW/3)

Comment: Hi @Nick, do you believe that’s easier than a ‘left join’/‘isnull’ approach?

Comment: @JaimeDrq a `LEFT JOIN` query won't return a row with 'principal' for any employee that has dependents. that's why the `UNION` is needed. See https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eeN6FCvAjVwYePbhyYwPzW/2

Comment: Thanks @Nick, this works perfectly, much appreciated

Comment: Hi @Nick, am trying to add where clause on the employees e.g. JOIN Dependents d on d.employee_No = e.employee_No WHERE e.policy = 9 AND d.policy = 9 but i cant get it to work, kindly could you explain how i can do this?

Comment: @Fredmax see this [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eeN6FCvAjVwYePbhyYwPzW/4) it should answer your question. Take note of the comment about the `JOIN` condition in the query

Answer (score 1):

How about this query:

`SELECT a.*, "principal" as 'relationship' FROM Employees a 
UNION SELECT b.* FROM Dependents b  ORDER BY employee_no DESC`

[DBFIDDLE here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qvndzfxAc23yPXbUj2nWfM/3)

Answer (score -1):

You can use join or Map the columns. Check the index in both the tables for your slowness of query. Index should be `employee_No` in both the tables. And then loop your query output.

```
<?php
    $qryOutput = array();
    $query = "SELECT A.*, B.* FROM Employees A LEFT JOIN Dependents B ON   A.employee_No=B.employee_No" // query

    $qryOutput = execute_Query($query); // Check this syntax. For Execute query


    // Loop through your Query Output
    foreach ($qryOutput as $key => $value) 
    {   echo $value["employee_No"]." ".$value["dependent_name"]." ".$value["relationship"]; }

 ?>
```

Comment: That won't return the expected outputs. Where are the principals?

Comment: only dependents are returned

Comment: Yes you are right. Employee without Dependents will not be coming in my query. Wait i will update my Answer @JaimeDrq Thank you.

Comment: I have updated my Answer can you check now? @Fredmax

Answer (score -2):

You can use either **INNER JOIN**  or **LEFT JOIN** to actualize it.

Try something like this. Though I have not tested the code.

Your table need to be created with foreign key references for it to work. see sample below. I have tested it.

```
create table Employees(employee_No int primary key,Employee_name varchar(100));

create table Dependents(employee_No int primary key,dependent_name varchar(100), relationship varchar(100)
 foreign key (employee_No) references Employees(employee_No));
```

Insert for testing

```
insert into Employees(employee_No,Employee_name) values(1558,'Bean');

insert into Employees(employee_No,Employee_name) values(1557,'Juliet');

insert into Dependents(employee_No,dependent_name,relationship) values(1558,'kevin','son');
```

**code**

```
<?php
$host = "localhost"; /* Host name */
$user = "root"; /* User */
$password = ""; /* Password */
$dbname = "your-db"; /* Database name */

$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password,$dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$con) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$query = 'SELECT Employees.employee_No, Employees.Employee_name, Dependents.employee_No, Dependents.dependent_name, 
Dependents.relationship FROM Employees
LEFT JOIN Dependents ON Employees.employee_No = Dependents.employee_No
ORDER BY Employees.Employee_name';

    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ 
  $empno = $row['employee_No'];
  $empname = $row['Employee_name'];
  $relation = $row['relationship'];
 $dependant_name = $row['dependent_name'];

//you can now echo

echo $dependant_name.' '.$relation.'<br/>';
}
?>
```

Comment: You cannot use inner join or left join. You must use left join, otherwise you won't ever see the principals

Comment: only dependents are returned

Comment: let me test run it

Comment: @Fredmax, I have updated my answer. You will need to create your table with foreign key reference. please see my answer

Comment: @Jamie, what principals are yo talking about. What i have tested and its working with either INNER JOIN or LEFT JOIN.  can you test the code yourself. See am angry with you because you made me loose 2 points. always research before you comment. This is in the case of next time!!!